# How can I create a line break on Bash while responding to a prompt?

Tags: bash

I'm creating a `README` file using Bash. When adding description in the file, I want the text to appear as 2 paragraphs. How can I create a line break after para one? I tried `"\n"` but nothing happened.

Comment: Use a heredoc, e.g. `cat << EOF` on one line. Then write your paragraphs and then put `EOF` on the line below you paragraphs. You can wrap it in a function an call it whenever you need it, or just include in once in your script,  up to you. If you want to write it to `stderr`, then `cat >&2 << EOF` and if you don't want variables expanded within your heredoc, single quote the sigil, e.g. the opening `'EOF'`. If you want to write it to the `README` file then use `cat >README << EOF` as the opening line. You are just redirecting to the file instead of `stdout` in that case.

Comment: If appending multiple outputs to `README` use `cat >>README << EOF`

Comment: `\n` is translated by bash into a line feed only in side of a `$'....'` construct. Example: `echo $'ab\ncd'`.

Answer (score 3):

Continuing from my comments. What you want to be able to write formatted blocks of text out to a file (or to the terminal `/dev/stdout`) is a `heredoc`. A heredoc will write the lines out as formatted between and opening and closing tag. (`EOF` is traditionally used, but it can be anything you like). The form is:

```bash
cat << EOF
  Your text goes here
  and here

  and here, etc...
EOF
```

If you want to write to a file, then use `cat >filename << EOF` as the opening. If you have variables in your text that you do not want expanded (e.g. `$myvar` you want written out as `$myvar` and not what it holds), quote the opening tag, e.g. `'EOF'`)

In your case if you want to write to a filename from within your script, then just use the form above. You can use default initialization to write to the terminal if no filename is given as an argument to your script, e.g.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

fname="${1:-/dev/stdout}"    # set filename to write to (stdout by default)

# heredoc
cat >"$fname" << EOF

  My dog has fleas and my cat has none. Lucky cat. My snake has
scales and can't have fleas. Lucky snake.

  If the animals weren't animals could they still have fleas?

EOF
```

If called with no argument, the heredoc is printed to the terminal (`/dev/stdout`). If given a filename, then the heredoc output is redirected to the filename, e.g.

```
$ bash write-heredoc.sh README
```

Fills the `README` file with the heredoc contents, e.g.

```
$ cat README

  My dog has fleas and my cat has none. Lucky cat. My snake has
scales and can't have fleas. Lucky snake.

  If the animals weren't animals could they still have fleas?
```

You can include blank lines as you like. If you want to append to your `README` file using multiple heredocs, then just use `cat >>filename << EOF` to append instead of truncate.